# Google Analytics APi to get new users

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using Reporting API v4 and method `reports:batchGet`. I want to get `new_users`. For this I can use

1. dimension `ga:userType` and metric `ga:sessions` or
2. only metric `ga:newUsers`.

Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

They are **not** the same, there may be a discrepancy between the two numbers.

**New User**: The session-level status of a user who has never visited the site before. You can appear as a new user twice over the course of two sessions.

**New Visitor**: The user-level status of a user who has never visited the site before. You can only appear as a new visitor once.

This relates to the fact that **GA automatically breaks and restarts sessions at midnight**.

If a new user is on the site at 11:40 PM, GA assigns a unique client ID cookie to them. This user is recognized in GA as a new visitor and a new user. 20 minutes later, the session breaks at midnight, and a new session is started on Day 2.

GA sees the same client ID and knows this is the same new user from before, despite a new session being force-started.

GA attributes this post-midnight session as having a new user again since they technically aren't a returning visitor, meaning we now have 2 sessions and 2 new user counts - one of each for both days.

Comment: Sorry, but there is no term 'visitor' in GA. User and visitor are synonyms.

Comment: NewUsers is a metric. New Visitor is a dimensions (it is a value of ga:userType) so there is term 'visitor' in GA. Anyway, the concept is the same and it is not depending on terms User/Visitor. A discrepancy between the two different report in the question can exist when a session breaks at midnight.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you'll get count of sessions for users who have been assigned a Client_ID in chosen period. In the second example – count of these users.